# Getting current step in checkout in PHP in Magento 1

Tags: checkout, magento-1, session, onestepcheckout

I got all of the steps using this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getData('steps')
```

**But how do I get the current step?** Not in prototype or js. I want it from PHP. I am using onestep checkout and ajax to get to the next step.

Comment: `onestep checkout `?? means.. you do not using magento default checkout!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the complete value from the step data.
So in your case, you'll have to look through the steps and check them:

```
$steps = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getData('steps');

foreach ($steps as $step) {
    if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getStepData($step, 'complete')) {
        continue;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Current step will be the value of the `$step` variable after running that code.

Comment: For some reason I get `false`. The `getStepData` returns me false. my phtml file is include from xml: `<checkout_onepage_index>`